# Powershell Variable Folder Name

Tags: powershell

I have a static path: `C:\Program Files\N-able Technologies\EndpointSetupInformation\`

And then a GUID folder, which is different per machine: `{10ba9c5f-8bc1-4094-c245-1e6a38d90090}` for instance, and the GUID folder is the only folder in the directory.

And then the exe file: `installer.exe`

I need to run that installer.exe with powershell. How can I do this simply? Basically something like: `C:\Program Files\N-able Technologies\EndpointSetupInformation\{*}\installer.exe`

Answer (score 3):

You can have the following which will allow you to assign the full path to a variable for use later.

```
$installer = (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\N-able Technologies\EndpointSetupInformation\*\installer.exe').FullName
```

This assumes that there is only one `installer.exe` file one folder deep.

You could drop the `.FullName` at the end and then use `$installer.FullName` instead, giving you access to all the other properties that the `Get-ChildItem` has, such as `.BaseName` or `.DirectoryName`